# S2SH run in weblogic error: <Exception occurred during processing request: Connection reset by peer: socket write error>

Tags: struts2, weblogic11g

My project is struts2 + spring + hibernate. Now, I found a problem when running in Weblogic with the error below.

Can someone help me? Thanks.

```
2014-11-01 15:10:04,718 ERROR [org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher] - <Exception occurred during processing request: Connection reset by peer: socket write error>
java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
    at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.writeChunkTransfer(ChunkOutput.java:507)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.writeChunks(ChunkOutput.java:486)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput.flush(ChunkOutput.java:382)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.CharsetChunkOutput.flush(CharsetChunkOutput.java:313)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutput$2.checkForFlush(ChunkOutput.java:580)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.CharsetChunkOutput.write(CharsetChunkOutput.java:221)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ChunkOutputWrapper.write(ChunkOutputWrapper.java:146)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletOutputStreamImpl.write(ServletOutputStreamImpl.java:138)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.StreamResult.doExecute(StreamResult.java:294)
    at
```

Comment: where is this error occurring? add more details please.

Comment: You need to give us more information about when the error occurs, code examples, etc. like Loopo mentioned